# Source of mediatimeline doesn't load properly when using relative path - WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to play some background music in a WPF application but the music does not play when I am using a relative path.

This does not work:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="PlaySoundStoryboard">
            <MediaTimeline Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  Source="pack://application:,,,/Music/music.mp3" />
</Storyboard>
```

However when I pick the full path as source it does work: 
(The music also plays when I do not run the application, but just have the code open in Visual Studio, so if anybody has a fix for that please let me know)

```
<Storyboard x:Key="PlaySoundStoryboard">
            <MediaTimeline Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  Source="D:\Documenten\Application\View\Music\music.mp3" />
</Storyboard>
```

I also tried just specifying the folder as suggested here: [Set Mediaelement Source to Relative URI in WPF Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533990/set-mediaelement-source-to-relative-uri-in-wpf-code)

```
<Storyboard x:Key="PlaySoundStoryboard">
        <MediaTimeline Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  Source="Music/music.mp3" />
```

The relative path does work when I use it for images so I am a little bit confused,
this works:

```
 <Button.Content>
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Img/music-and-multimedia.png"/>
 </Button.Content>
```

Edit: Here is my media element

```
    <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement"  />
    <Button Name="playbutton" Grid.Column="0" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button.Content>
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Img/music-and-multimedia.png"/>
        </Button.Content>

    </Button>
    <Button Name="stopbutton" Grid.Column="1" Width="40" Height="40" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button.Content>
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Img/mute.png"/>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

And here are my Grid.Triggers:

```
     <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PlaySoundStoryboard}"  Name="theStoryboard"  />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="playbutton">
            <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="theStoryboard" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="stopbutton">
            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="theStoryboard" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
```

Comment: Did you make sure to set your mp3 file `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy Always`? If not, the file is not copied in the bin directory and the relative path doesn't point to anything at run time.

Comment: Mp3 file is set to Copy Always.

Comment: Please include a full XAML example showing your `MediaElement`, because I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I made an edit in the original post.

Comment: This piece of code works for me, so you probably have a resource issue? Make sure you create resources before referencing them.
`    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement"/>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <MediaTimeline Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  Source="/Music/music.mp3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to resolve this problem by extracting audio/media content from a resources and write it to the temporary file. Then set URI for the MediaTimeline source to make reference to the temporary file.

```
var resourceName = "YourAssemblyName.Music.music.mp3"; // Embedded resource 
using (var fstream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    var ext = resourceName.Substring(resourceName.LastIndexOf("."));
    var pathfile = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
    using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(pathfile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fstream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
    }
    // "mt" is name of the MediaTimeline element 
    mt.Source = new Uri(pathfile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

Remove the temporary created file `pathfile` when it no longer needed.